# How to enable the blender console?

Tags: console, blender

I have installed Blender 2.65a from its official site but am unable to activate the console for python. I'm unable to run in terminal since it is not installed from Ubuntu Software Center because it is five versions lagging in the repo.

However, I tried to drag the executable blender file to the terminal, Blender opened but without the console.

Answer (score 7):

First things first, the Blender Console on Linux is a bit different than you might expect.

Unlike on Windows, Blender's console output is placed on the command line, if run from a terminal. Also, Blender on all versions contains a built in console.
[image]

You can choose either a Python console or a regular console (bash), though some builds do not have this (for example the one I'm using does not).

Secondly, you can get Blender [from a PPA](https://launchpad.net/~irie/+archive/blender). The builds are from svn and are built usually every week. The PPA also contains Blender 2.4x for backwards compatibility.

**For 2.6x:**

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:irie/blender
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install blender
```

**For 2.4:**

```
sudo apt-get install blender 2.4
```

Comment: I think the command is most likely `sudo apt-get install blender2.4` but I can't edit it.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to:
open terminal then type cd "your blender path"
example: cd /home/daniel/Desktop/DevAPPS/blender-2.79
then launch the blender in terminal, type in terminal: ./blender
then its all done.

Answer (score 1):

I return to this problem on a regular basis, and I usually find this answer when I am searching for the solution, so I figured I should add it here:

Another step that was missed, once you have installed Blender, is to go to the `/usr/share/applications` folder and open the `blender*` desktop file in a text editor, as root user (if it is updating from the PPA, it will append the svn version number to the application name).

I use the terminal to open `gedit` using: `gksu gedit`, but you could also use the key command <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, and enter the same command.

Change the preference `Terminal=False` to read `Terminal=True`, then save, and start blender, which should now open from a console/terminal window. The console will remain open, so long as blender is running (but blender will shut down if you exit the console).

This fix may only be necessary for 12.04, and does not apply to earlier versions which use the Alacarte menu system, which will allow you to add this preference with a radio button.

Answer (score 1):

#### Edit your launcher

Open up your `blender.desktop` file in `~/.local/share/applications` or `/usr/share/applications/blender.desktop` with a *Text Editor* of your choice (*Sublime*, *Gedit* etc.):

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Blender
Exec=/opt/blender-2.77a/blender %F
Icon=/opt/blender-2.77a/icons/scalable/apps/blender.svg
MimeType=application/x-blender
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=false
Type=Application
```

and set the 'Terminal flag' to `true`:

```
...
Terminal=true
...
```

This will run Blender *with the Terminal* window:

[image]

**Note:** To create a 'launcher' for Blender before, see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/115149/334867).

Answer (score 0):

@ Alaa, is correct, but i could not open the blender* icon in text editor so i just fallowed these steps

1. from terminal run `gksu gedit`
2. It asks for password, enter it. it opens gedit
3. open **home folder** and navigate to `/usr/share/applications`
4. select the **Blender*** icon; drag it into into **gedit** window
5. Change the preference **`Terminal=False`** to read **`Terminal=True`**
6. save and close it
7. run blender and the **blender terminal** too opens :)

@ Alaa solution in more step by step manner.